# How does experience work in Dungeon Defenders?

Tags: dungeon-defenders

While playing Dungeon Defenders with friends, some of them aren't gaining as much experience as others.  We started to worry Squires were kill stealing the Apprentices.  But in the end we couldn't figure out how exactly our characters gain experience.

So how do you gain experience:

Is it by damage dealt?
Is more last hit style?
How does this apply to defense structures?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For the PC version of the game, experience is shared for all kills. So all kills will give all players the same amount of XP, regardless of who killed them.

The [Experience](http://dungeondefenders.wikia.com/wiki/Experience) page on the wikia supports this:

> On the PC version, experience from killing creatures is shared among the entire party.

Comment: +1 This is my experience of the topic and there's support from a few commenters on the other answer. I've also added a reference for you.

Comment: The accepted answer is out of date in this case. It used to be that way, but in one of the patches that behaviour changed so that all present players gain experience from kills.