# If I upgrade another players Tower, how is the XP divided?

Tags: dungeon-defenders

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does experience work in Dungeon Defenders?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/33044/how-does-experience-work-in-dungeon-defenders)

In a multiplayer game, if Player **1** deploys a Lighting Tower he will receive the associated XP for every creature it kills. If Player **2** *upgrades* the tower before the next round, does Player **1** still get all of the XP earned by the tower?